Rashba spin-orbit coupling for band structure in Quantum ESPRESSO?
I want to perform self-consistent field (SCF) calculations for monolayer graphene considering Rashba spin-orbit coupling (SOC) using Quantum ESPRESSO. I want to find band structure.
May I please have an input file for this?

As far as I understand, the Rashba type of spin-orbit coupling comes from the inversion symmetry broken, which acts as an external electric field perpendicular to the graphene basal plane and results in the degeneracy of bands released in the reciprocal space. In other words, all you need to do is induce the inversion symmetry broken in the graphene system through changing the crystal structure and you will have the Rashba type of spin-orbit coupling; rahter than setting any flag in the DFT calculation.

so what i addin my scf file

how can i make my scf file according to soc

i apply high relativistic pseudo

If you are talking about the spin-orbit coupling effect, you indeed need to set up some flags in the SCF calculation; besides, the relativistic pseudopotential. Please, refer to the manual of pw.x code.(https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PW.html) If you are talking about the Rashba-type SOC, you do not need to add any flag in the SCF calculation.

Sir I want to calculate Rashba-type SOC for monolayer graphene. Can you share 1 example or tutorial how scf file look when we apply Rashba effect
